TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function when running npm install
My application got a .net backend and js frontend for the UI side. The UI part got a package.json file like below-




{
  "name": "Scripts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "init.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "abcd",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-datetimepicker": "https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/tarball/v4.14.30",
    "crossroads": "^0.12.0",
    "date-format-lite": "^0.6.0",
    "devbridge-autocomplete": "^1.2.24",
    "glob": "^4.3.2",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-min": "^0.1.0",
    "grunt-sass": "^1.2.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.1.0",
    "jasmine-waits-for-callback": "^0.1.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery.fancytree": "2.21.0",
    "knockout": "3.3.0",
    "load-grunt-config": "^0.16.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^2.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.10.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.15",
    "requirejs-text": "^2.0.12",
    "signals": "^1.0.0",
    "spin": "0.0.1"
  }
}


The applications' csproj file got these lines -
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="blah blah blah" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <MySourceFiles Include="..\abcs.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" />
    <Exec Command="npm install" WorkingDirectory="..\ui" />
    <Exec Command="npm rebuild node-sass" WorkingDirectory="..\ui" />
    <Exec Command="grunt build --force" WorkingDirectory="..\ui" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="GenerateWebConfigs" />
  </Target>

When building the project, I get npm error like below-
> gifsicle@0.1.2 postinstall D:\app\ui\node_modules\node-minifier\node_modules\gifsicle
02:44:48   > node lib/check.js
02:44:48   
02:44:48   Downloading gifsicle.exe: 8%
02:44:48   fs.js:136
02:44:48       throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();
02:44:48       ^
02:44:48   
02:44:48   TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
02:44:48       at makeCallback (fs.js:136:11)
02:44:48       at Object.chmod (fs.js:1013:14)
02:44:48       at WriteStream.<anonymous> (D:\app\ui\node_modules\node-minifier\node_modules\gifsicle\lib\check.js:40:6)
02:44:48       at WriteStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
02:44:48       at lazyFs.close (internal/fs/streams.js:207:14)
02:44:48       at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
02:44:49   npm WARN Scripts@1.0.0 No description
02:44:49   npm WARN Scripts@1.0.0 No repository field.
02:44:49   
02:44:49   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
02:44:49   npm ERR! errno 1
02:44:49   npm ERR! gifsicle@0.1.2 postinstall: `node lib/check.js`
02:44:49   npm ERR! Exit status 1
02:44:49   npm ERR! 
02:44:49   npm ERR! Failed at the gifsicle@0.1.2 postinstall script.
02:44:49   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
02:44:49   
02:44:49   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
02:44:49   npm ERR!     C:\Users\SourceTask\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-06T07_44_49_270Z-debug.log
02:44:49 D:\app.csproj(926,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 1.

My project uses nodejs version 10 on the build server.
Tried adding latest gifsicle version in package.json, but no luck. Please help to fix this issue.
